# After moving to a new server, the website failed to load...socket error

Tags: python, django

I was working on a website for a school project. Recently the website was moved to a new server by the IT people from school. And I found that the website could not load anymore.

I am new to django and python, so I am very lost at this point...

I will really appreciate any suggestions or comments! Thanks a lot!

The error log shows that:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "application.fcgi", line 19,
>   in  runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false") File
>   "/home/foldera/Envs/django1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py",
>   line 182, in runfastcgi WSGIServer(get_internal_wsgi_application(),
>   **wsgi_opts).run() File "/home/foldera/Envs/django1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py",
>   line 114, in run ret = ThreadedServer.run(self, sock) File
>   "/home/foldera/Envs/django1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup/server/threadedserver.py",
>   line 84, in run clientSock, addr = sock.accept() socket.error: [Errno
>   22] Invalid argument

fcji Setting:

```
#!/home/spatialtest/Envs/django1.6/bin/python

# Set up the virtual environment:
import os, sys
os.environ.setdefault('PATH', '/bin:/usr/bin')
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/spatialtest/Envs/django1.6/bin:' +     os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = '/home/spatialtest/Envs/djano1.6/bin'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/spatialtest/Envs/django1.6/bin'
os.chdir('/home/spatialtest/public_html/spatialtest')

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/spatialtest/public_html/spatialtest")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to the file in the
# application directory with the db settings etc.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "django_project.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Comment: how are your starting your server? What do you settings look like?

Comment: Basically, the server is based on Apache. And it was just upgraded from 2.22 to 2.4. We used the fastcgi to deploy the website.